# Getting pager to show on magento list

Tags: php, list, magento, pager

We currently have a quote page which lists all existing quotes that we would like to show the pager.

We have the following code in the List page which we've added the call to the pager but it doesn't appear to be showing frontend at all.

I've also added the history page which displays a list with a pager as an example of a working page we are trying to emulate.

Can anyone point us in the right direction as we appear to be missing something

**List**

```
<?php $_quotation = $this->getQuotations();?>
<?php if($_quotation->getSize()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<table cellspacing="0" class="data-table" id="my-quotations-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="quote-quote"><?php echo $this->__('Quote #') ?></th>
            <th class="quote-date"><?php echo $this->__('Creation Date') ?></th>
            <th class="quote-valid"><?php echo $this->__('Valid until') ?></th>
            <th class="quote-status"><?php echo $this->__('Status') ?></th>
            <th class="quote-view-link">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->getQuotations() as $_quotation): ?>
            <?php $_quotation->checkExpirationDateAndApply(); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $_quotation->getincrement_id() ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->formatDate($_quotation->getcreated_time()) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->formatDate($_quotation->getValidEndTime()); ?>
                <td><?php echo $this->__($_quotation->getstatus()); ?></td>
                <td class="a-center"><?php if ($_quotation->isViewableByCustomer()): ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_quotation) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Quotation') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-quotations-table')</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You have no quotes available.') ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

**History**

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $_orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>
<div class="pager"><?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php if($_orders->getSize()): ?>
<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Delivery To') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Status') ?></span></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
            <td><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->htmlEscape($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
            <td><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
            <td class="a-center">
                <span class="nobr"><a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                    <?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                    <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-orders-table');</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You have placed no orders.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Layout block for List

```
<quotation_quote_list>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns-account.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="Quotation/Frontend_Grid" name="quotationslist" as="quotationslist" template="Quotation/List.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</quotation_quote_list>
```

Comment: Can you show layout updates for both pages? Seems like pager block isn't included on the list page.

Comment: Have updated above with the layout block for list... looks like it is missing the pager. What should we add in here?

Comment: And where is <block type="page/html_pager" name="some name here" /> ? You haven't added pager block to the page, why should it appear on the page?

Comment: Just adding the <block type="page/html_pager" name="quote_pager" /> breaks the page... any ideas on where to look next?

Comment: What do you mean "breaks page"? Show me your layout update with pager block. You should add pager block to page via layout update. Another solution is add pager block in your block class code which is much worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can implement custom model collection with magento pagination by extending `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` class in our block class.  Suppose I want to display users blog posts with pagination. Here is the steps to implement it easily:

1. Create a block class (posts.php) and add the below code in it.

   ```
   class Blog_User_Block_Posts extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
   {
       protected function _beforeToHtml()
       {
           $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();
           $collection = $this->_getPostsCollection();
           $toolbar->setCollection($collection);     /*(Add toolbar to collection)*/
           return parent::_beforeToHtml();
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the `view.phptml` file add the below code in it

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
   ```