# Magento <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?> is not working

Tags: magento, pagination

I am Using magento 1.6 version.
Pagination is not working on my `list.phtml`.
I am using this code `<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>` in `toolbar.phtml`.

I need pagination on my category view.

Is there any option to disable pagination from magento admin?

Comment: There already was questions about [Getting pager to show on magento list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6476807/517595) and question [Pager not working in Product List Catalog Block](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/79791/) in Magento Forum

Comment: See your HTML code, using some tool browser(firebug 4 example) search for class="toolbar" and note if it unable, but there are, ok. This way it's just only take css file styles.css, search for .toolbar,.toolbar .pager, ... .sorter and clean the visibilty:hidden; or display:none; into css file.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this helps as I found the solution through this question somehow - when I upgraded from 1.5 the pagers weren't working. To get the `getPagerHtml()` code working, I needed to update `catalog.xml` file. I've added the `page/html_pager` block inside the `catalog/product_list_toolbar` block as below:

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

Comment: This is already by default there, but still pagination is not showing.